# How to calculate the trajectory of a high speed projectile on earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile

Let’s say you launch a high velocity ($2-8km/s$) projectile from the earth at the equator. How do you calculate the trajectory of the projectile in the absence of drag? Is there a simple formula that I can use?

Comment: What kind of velocity are we talking about here?  50 m/s?  500?  5000?  More?

Comment: Make the moon for a more realistic path without air resistance.

Comment: Hypersonic to just below orbital velocity.

Comment: Why neglect drag? Do you also want to neglect the Earth's rotational speed?

Answer (score 2):

In the *complete* absence of drag a ballistic projectile will travel along an ellipse until it impacts the surface of the Earth.

If fired horizontally from sea level (and assuming a perfectly spherical Earth) at a speed between circular orbit speed (about 8 km/s) and escape velocity (about 11 km/s) then it will complete a full orbit and return to the firing location. If fired from sea level at a lower speed, it will impact the Earth before it completes one orbit. If fired at a higher speed then it will enter an open orbit and (probably) never return to Earth.

Essentially you have created a short-lived satellite in a very low orbit.

Comment: Worth noting the projectile completes a full orbit and returns to the firing location only if its speed is high enough but not too high. Below about 7km/s the projectile won't make it around, and above about 11km/s it won't ever come back.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Good point - I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What is going to happen is the object is going to follow an *elliptical* path, where the far focal point of the ellipse is going to be on the center of mass of the earth.

[image: fig1]

Assume you launch with less than orbital velocity, the path on the ellipse is going to intersect with the surface of the earth at some point (see splat above) and the object is going to "land" back on earth.

The polar coordinates of the path from the center of the earth is $$ r(\varphi) = \frac{ a (1-\epsilon^2)}{1+\epsilon \cos \varphi}$$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the ellipse, $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse (make the semi-minor axis equal to $b = a \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2})$ and $\varphi$ the polar coordinate angle, starting from $\varphi=0$.

If the path starts at a height $h$ above the surface of the earth with radius $R_{\rm earth}$, and is launched horizontally with speed $v_0$, then the ellipse parameters $(a,\epsilon)$ are

$$ a = R_{\rm earth} + h $$
$$ \epsilon = \sqrt{ 1 -  \frac{a\, v_0^2}{G M_{\rm earth}}}$$

where  $G$ is the universal gravity constant, and $M_{\rm earth}$ the mass of the earth.

Comment: FWIW, GM of Earth is ~398600.435507 km³/s², see https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html